# Azure project is not loading

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to load a Solution that includes Azure projects.

When I open the solution Visual Studio tells me that I need to install the newer version of the Azure for .Net, which is October 2012.

[image]

When I click **"OK"**, it's downloading Azure and trying to install it with Web Platform Installer. The **"Install"** button is disabled as it is already installed.

[image]

**This is how solution looks like**

[image]

**Here is my Program List**

[image]

Every time I open the solution, this is what happens. The solution is not buildable. 
Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: please anyone help. This was super urgent. I don't want to reinstall the windows and VS so bad.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling just the SDK?  If you create a brand new project does it reload?  If so you could consider pulling the existing code into a new project shell(s) or - being VERY careful with backups - take a look at a working project vs. failing one, compare project type GUIDs in the prj files, and try to manually tweak.  That's playing with fire a bit, but I sensed a bit of desperation :)

Comment: i tired that. even a new project was not being created. so, I reinstalled the whole OS. and then worked. I asked this question coz I really didn't want to reinstall the Windows. but I had no other options, so I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to reinstall the Windows. Then everything just worked fine.

Comment: there is nothing more painful than reinstalling a .net developers Windows.

Comment: That is really cardinal solution.